# Disable date depend on vacation days on table in mysql

Tags: mysql, extjs4, codeigniter-3

**im trying to disable date depend on vacation days using this syntax but instead i get is the date are all disabled**

```
 function GetHariLibur(){
            $tanggal = date('Y');
            $sql = ("select DATE_FORMAT(TANGGAL, '%d-%m-%Y') as TANGGAL from m_hari_libur where TANGGAL like '" . $tanggal . "%'");
            $rows = $this->db->Execute($sql)->GetRows();
            return $rows;  
          }
```

the "m_hari_libur is the table contains the list of vacation days", and the "Tanggal is a date example 01-02-2020"

**this is another function that called "GetHariLibur"**

```
function jurnal_harian_form() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL,"US");
        echo "<h3 id='title'>Jurnal Harian :: Daftar SKP :: Form Jurnal Harian</h3>";
        $_GET['nip'] = ($_SESSION['NIP']);
        $data_profil_pegawai = $this->jurnal_mdl->get_data_statistik_Jabatan();
        $harilibur = $this->jurnal_mdl->GetHariLibur();
        $currentYear = date("Y");
        $month = strftime("%B");
        $min =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +5 days"));
        $now =  date('Y-m-d');

        $r =0;
        for ($i=1; $i < 6 ; $i++) { 
            $gg = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("$i $month $currentYear"));
            $issun = date('w',strtotime("$gg"));
            if ($issun == '6' || $issun == '0') {
                $min =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$min +1 days"));
                $r++;
            } 

        }

        $hasilmin = '';
        $hasilmax = '';
        if($now >= $min){
            $hasilmin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of $month $currentYear"));
            if ($r == 1) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +1 month +6 days"));
            } elseif($r == 2) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +1 month +7 days"));
            }else{
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +1 month +5 days"));
            }  
        }else if($now == $min){
            $hasilmin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of $month $currentYear -1 month"));
            if ($r == 1) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +5 days"));
            } elseif($r == 2) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +6 days"));
            }else{
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +4 days"));
            }
        }else{
            $hasilmin = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of $month $currentYear -1 month"));
            if ($r == 1) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +5 days"));
            } elseif($r == 2) {
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +6 days"));
            }else{
                $hasilmax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$month $currentYear +4 days"));
            } 
        }
        $data = array(
            "html_store" => $this->get_store_form_tambah_jurnal(),
            "pegawai"    => $data_profil_pegawai,
            "harilibur"  => $harilibur,
            "minvalue"   => $hasilmin,
            "maxvalue"   => $hasilmax
        );
        $this->load->view('jurnal/grid_jurnal_harian2', $data);
    }
```

**Below is is the View called grid_jurnal_harian2.php this view is for disable the date using ext-js**

```
items: [{
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            name: 'TANGGAL',
                            fieldLabel: 'Tanggal',
                            value: tanggal,
                            disabledDays : [0,6],
                            disabledDates: '<?php echo $harilibur ?>',
                            // disabledDates: ["01-01-2020", "25-01-2020", "22-03-2020", "25-03-2020", "10-04-2020", "01-05-2020", "07-05-2020", "21-05-2020", "22-05-2020", "24-05-2020", "25-05-2020", "26-05-2020", "27-05-2020", "01-06-2020", "31-07-2020", "17-08-2020", "20-08-2020", "29-11-2020", "25-12-2020"],
                            maxValue: '<?php echo $maxvalue; ?>',
                            minValue:  '<?php echo $minvalue; ?>',
                            format: 'd-m-Y',
                            submitFormat: 'Y-m-d',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            anchor: '50%',
                            handler: function() {

                            }
                        },
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non sql stuff for now, and instead focus on getting a working query

Comment: so is there any sugestion @Strawberry ??